# Apply two Folds or Getters and only succeed when both succeed

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

Imagine I have the following list:

```
lst :: [(Bool, Maybe Integer)]
lst = [(True, Just 3), (True, Nothing), (False, Just 12)]
```

Using the lens library, I want to extract the elements of the tuples, but I only want it to succeed when the second element is `Just`. I want some optic, *`split`* that works like this:

```
> lst ^.. folded.split (_1.to not) (_2._Just)
[(False, 3), (True, 12)]
```

I can implement `split` myself like this:

```
split :: Getting (First a) s a -> Getting (First b) s b -> Fold s (a, b)
split a b = folding (\x -> (,) <$> (x ^? a) <*> (x ^? b))
```

…which seems to work. However, this seems like I must be reinventing the wheel. Is there something already provided by the lens library that accomplishes this in an equally nice way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`aside`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.3/docs/Control-Lens-Prism.html#v:aside) combinator takes a `Prism` that works over the second component of a tuple and returns a `Prism` that works over the whole tuple:

```
ghci> lst ^.. folded.aside _Just
[(True,3),(False,12)]
```

The resulting prism matches when the component is matched, otherwise it fails.

Combining it with `to` and `bimap`, we can reproduce your example:

```
ghci> lst ^.. folded.aside _Just.to (bimap not id)
[(False,3),(True,12)]
```

To work over the first component, we can use [`swapped`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.3/docs/Control-Lens-Iso.html#t:Swapped):

```
ghci> [(Just 3,False)]^..folded.swapped.aside _Just.swapped
[(3,False)]
```